# Millis for a given date are wrong using Date.parse(dateString)

Tags: java, date, milliseconds

I have a date string of `1/1/1970 8:00 AM`

The correct millis should be `8 hours * 60 minutes per hour * 60000 milliseconds per minute = 28800000`

However, using `Date.parse(dateString)` returns `50400000`

What am I not understanding?

**Edit**

I originally tried using date.getTime();

Here's my original code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a");
dateFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                     
sb.append(month).append("/");
sb.append(day).append("/");
sb.append(year).append(" ");
sb.append(pad(hour)).append(":");
sb.append(pad(minute)).append(" ");;
sb.append(ampm);
Date date = new Date();

date = dateFmt.parse(sb.toString());

date.getTime()
```

Comment: Why would you use deprecated `Date.parse()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of your local timezone. Use Simple date format with timezone as below to get your desired value against `UTC` timezone:

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    String dateS = "1/1/1970 8:00 AM";
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  
    format.setLenient(true);
    Date date = format.parse(dateS);
    System.out.println(date.getTime()); //<-- prints 28800000
```

or more compact:

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  
    Date date = format.parse("1/1/1970 8:00 AM");
    System.out.println(date.getTime());  //<-- prints 28800000
```

Answer (score 7):

This is almost certainly the problem:

> If no time zone is specified, the local time zone is assumed.

My guess is that you're in a time zone which was at UTC-6 at the Unix epoch, so 8am local time was 2pm UTC.

Then there's the more fundamental problem of you using deprecated methods when there are better alternative (`SimpleDateFormat`, which allows you to set the time zone) available. Methods are deprecated for a *reason*. You shouldn't just use deprecated methods regardless, otherwise you'll keep running into things like this.

In fact, you'd be better off using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) if you possibly can - but at *least* stay away from the deprecated methods in `Date`.

Sample code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
long millis = format.parse(text).getTime();
```

You may want to change `dd/MM` to `MM/dd`, depending on what format your dates are going to be in - we can't tell from "01/01". Note the explicit setting of both time zone and locale.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat returns a Date object, I want it as a long.  Please show me how this can be done using the method that you recommend, thank you!

Comment: +1@Jon Skeet. But you could've tried to tell him where he lived rather than the tz info. 'How did you know?' :-)

Comment: @AndroidAddict: `Date.getTime()` perhaps? (And really, it's not hard to read the documentation to get that...)

Comment: I have used that method too and still get the same result.  Please show me an example.  Also, please keep your comments constructive, because it may be you that is not understanding something.

Comment: @Android Addict: Jon Skeet not understanding something? That's pretty funny.

Comment: @AndroidAddict: If you use `SimpleDateFormat` and set the time zone to UTC, then call `getTime()` on the result, you'll get the answer you expect. Honestly.

Comment: @John Skeet I understand what my issue was now.  I was calculating top of day in milliseconds and adding that to a time value.  Since both were corrected for time zone, the result was always off by the doubling of the time zone offset.  Should I have added another adjusted time, it would have been off by another tzo offset.  Thanks for helping, I wish I could have voted for both but the other answer actually gave me the key.

Comment: @AndroidAddict: You should *never* be adding one date/time to another. The concept make no sense. It's like adding a point to a point. You should only ever add a "duration" (a number of milliseconds) to a date/time - this is like adding a *vector* to a point, which makes more sense. Joda Time separates these concepts more clearly.

Comment: @John Skeet essentially that is what I was doing.  I always add longs, in this case the 8 hours past 0 (a duration) and the top on the day in milliseconds.  Perhaps i did not say it eloquently.

Comment: @AndroidAddict: But you've fetched that value by parsing a date/time string. You *really* shouldn't do that.

Comment: @John Skeet I was just trying to create some mock data for testing.  Normally that value gets supplied differently.  Thanks for pointing out best practices!  :^)

Comment: @AndroidAddict: In this case, the *far* better way of providing the data would be to use `TimeUnit`: `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(8)`.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:

**You do not need to form the string:** You can use [`LocalDateTime#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-) to create an instance of `LocalDateTime` which can be converted into an `Instant` in order to get the number of milliseconds from the Unix epoch.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year = 1970, month = 1, dayOfMonth = 1, hour = 8, minute = 0;
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute);
        Instant instant = ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(instant.toEpochMilli());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
28800000
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rsmf5u)

**If you already have a date-time string in the given format:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u h:m a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strDateTime = "1/1/1970 8:00 AM";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);

        Instant instant = ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(instant.toEpochMilli());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
28800000
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/z5oOmz)

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>